# Use interpolation in constraint function inside Ecto migrations.

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have the following migration in one of my applications

```
use Ecto.Migration
  alias SnitchPayments.PaymentMethodCode

  @code PaymentMethodCode.hosted_payment() |> to_charlist() # this evaulautes to 'hpm'

  def change do
    create table("snitch_hosted_payments", comment: "payments made via hosted payments") do
      add(:transaction_id, :string)
      add(:payment_source, :string)
      add(:raw_response, :map)
      add(:payment_id, references("snitch_payments", on_delete: :delete_all), null: false)
      timestamps()
    end

    create unique_index("snitch_hosted_payments", :payment_id,
      comment: "one-to-one relationship")

    create constraint("snitch_hosted_payments",
      :hosted_payment_exclusivity,
      check: "payment_exclusivity(payment_id, #{@code}) = 1")
  end
```

As you can see I am trying to interpolate in this line `"payment_exclusivity(payment_id, #{@code}) = 1"`. But, on running the migration I am getting the error

`** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42703 (undefined_column): column "hpm" does not exist`

"payment_exclusivity()" is a function in postgres which is I am calling with the given params.

The following works if I do:

```
create constraint("snitch_hosted_payments",
          :hosted_payment_exclusivity,
          check: "payment_exclusivity(payment_id, 'hpm') = 1")
```

What could be the right way to do this interpolation? I don't want to hardcode the value here.

Comment: What do you get if you add single quotes to the `#{@code}`?

Comment: Doing `'#{@code}'` surrounding the expression with single quotes, would that make a difference?

Comment: `check: fragment("payment_exclusivity(payment_id, ?) = 1", @code)` would probably work.

Comment: Thanks, @AbdullahEsmail '#{@code}' works. @mudasobwa the approach looks good but I did not want to import `Ecto.Query` inside the module, since the interpolation with single quotes works. Thanks, people for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, I'll write the solution that worked for OP here as an answer to this question can be marked as "answered".

The suggested solution was surrounding `#{@code}` with single quotes:

`check: "payment_exclusivity(payment_id, '#{@code}') = 1")`

which worked for Arjun.